# what are the usual problems that we face with sincedb in logstash

Tags: logstash

I am using ELK stack, so using file input plugin in logstash i am working on it

at first i used file*.txt to match with file pattern
later i used masterfile.txt as a single file which has the data of all matching patterns

and now i am going back to file*.txt , but here i see the problem- I am seeing the data on kibana which is the date after the file*.txt is replaced with masterfile.txt but not the history,

I feel like i must understand the behavior of sincedb logstash here
also a possible solution to get the history data

Answer (score 0):

Logstash stores information about the position of the last byte read in the file that contains the logs with **sincedb_path**. During the execution, Logstash starts reading the input file from the mentioned position.

Take into account 'start_position' and the name of the index ( Logstash -> output) if you want to create a new index with different logs.

https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/plugins-inputs-file.html#plugins-inputs-file-sincedb_path